# Ceph on Docker Swarm from Compose

Tags: docker, ceph, swarm

I want to deploy Ceph cluster on Docker Swarm.

For first I try to deploy just monitor...
Yaml compose file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  Mon:
    image: ceph/daemon:tag-build-master-kraken-ubuntu-16.04
    #command: ceph mon
    environment:
      - "CEPH_DAEMON=MON"
      - "NETWORK_AUTO_DETECT=1"
#      - "MON_IP=192.168.0.20"
#      - "CEPH_PUBLIC_NETWORK=192.168.0.0/24"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: etc_ceph
        target: /etc/ceph
      - type: volume
        source: var_lib_ceph
        target: /var/lib/ceph/
    network_mode: host
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.DFS==true

volumes:
    etc_ceph:
    var_lib_ceph:
    dev:
```

But its don't working, in logs i see:

2017-10-08 20:09:07  /entrypoint.sh: ERROR- it looks like we have not been able to discover the network settings

May be exist something working sample?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to use host network, but option `network_mode: host` is [not supported](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#not-supported-for-docker-stack-deploy) in Swarm. Swarm flavour would be:

```
services:
  Mon:
    ...
    networks:
      hostnet: {}

networks:
  hostnet:
    external: true
    name: host
```

From: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#host-or-none
Also, complete **CephFS in Swarm** example available at https://github.com/sepich/ceph-swarm